# Filter checkbox fields from visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a `Visualforce Page` with some fields, all of which are check box fields.
If I created record by selecting some check box fields only. But how should 
I filter the only selected fields in Visualforce Page?

How can I filter the selected fields only?

Here is my page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="DataInsert">
 <apex:form >
     <div style="border:1px solid; width:200px;">
    <div style="height:30px;width:150px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px;

                     font-size:15px;color:blue;">
            Incident Fields 
         </div>
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Imtpact
             </td>
             <td>
                 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!impact}"/>
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>
                 Incident_state
             </td>
             <td>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!incident_state}"/>
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>
                 Short_description
             </td>
             <td>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!short_description}"/>
             </td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
             <td>
                 sys_id
             </td>
             <td>
                 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sys_id}"/>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Contact_type
             </td>
             <td>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contact_type}"/>
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>
                 U_sftype
             </td>
             <td>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!u_sftype}"/>
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>
                 sys_updated_onONLast
             </td>
             <td>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sys_updated_onONLast}"/>
             </td>
             </tr>
         <tr >
             <td colspan="2" align="center">
                 <apex:commandButton value="INSERT" style="color:red;" action="{!doInsert}" />
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     </div>

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check them in your controller using `if` condition. Here is once code sample for your reference.

```
public void yourmethod(){
 // some code here
 if(short_description){
   //its true so execute your code
}
if(impact){
//its true so execute your code
}
//Same for all checkbox.

}
```